# Error when updating/installing 'XML' package on R

Tags: r, xml, package

I am unable to update XML package on my R from version 3.98-1.20 to 3.99-0.1, or to install it from scratch after removing. This is what I receive in RStudio console when installing XML from scratch:

```
> install.packages("XML")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/rstundz/Desktop/My Software/R/win-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
       binary   source needs_compilation
XML 3.98-1.20 3.99-0.1              TRUE

installing the source package ‘XML’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/XML_3.99-0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 968578 bytes (945 KB)
downloaded 945 KB

* installing *source* package 'XML' ...
** package 'XML' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
sed: can't read NAMESPACE.in: No such file or directory
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'XML'
* removing 'C:/Users/rstundz/Desktop/My Software/R/win-library/XML'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘XML’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\rstundz\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpaI9Z0t\downloaded_packages’
```

I am using R version 3.6.2. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: When it asked you, did you choose binary or source? What if you do `install.packages("XML", type="binary")`. You are probably fine with the pre-compiled binary version.

Comment: Thanks, this actually solves the issue. I believe I should indeed be fine with a binary version - I don't use XML on its own, it's there just as a dependency for other packages. After consulting with my colleagues, I realise the error is related to the 'NAMESPACE.in' file within the package. I have downloaded the latest version manually as an archive file, and can confirm that it contains the 'NAMESPACE.in' file just as every other package does. Therefore something must be preventing R from reading it, and I can't figure out what. Either way, I'll stick to the binary version for now. Thanks!